# How to find position in file according to the import warning line?

Tags: import, axapta

I have export .xpo file with lots of tables in it. The tables exists in the system. When I try to import that .xpo by command import I get some of

```
Warning Message (09:31:48 am)   Import warning (line 510) skipping property Validate.
```

warnings. It looks like the line number do not correspond to the line in file. (The property Validate is not near line 510 in file when I open it in text editor.) How do I find which table(s) this error(s) are related to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue and check `%USERPROFILE%\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax\Log\*Import.log` as per Matej's advice but its size was 0 so it didn't help.

The stack trace when the warning is thrown looks as follows:

```
\Classes\Info\add
\Classes\xInfo\importElement
\Classes\SysImportElements\importElements                           38
\Classes\SysImportElements\import                                   46
\Forms\SysImportDialog\Methods\import                               30
\Forms\SysImportDialog\Designs\DesignList\Import\Methods\Clicked     3
```

You can set a breakpoint in `\Classes\Info\add` and when a warning is displayed check the value of `tmpImportAot.TreeNodeName` in the debugger in `\Classes\SysImportElements\importElements` - it will contain the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `%USERPROFILE%\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax\Log\*Import.log` file for the details of the import process.

Answer (score 0):

I find a second way how to solve this. I export tables I imported by this file and compare what I was importing with want was exported from that import and I find a difference which leads to problems.

P.S.: 10p solution is working too.